# base32 deep grok in bash on my way to native reed-solomon

Tags: linux, bash, base32

Is there an *elegant* way to do this in Linux or OS X?

```
$ echo -n 'hello' | base32
```

Or better yet, using only pure bash syntax to do the same. For example, this code uses no external commands just bash.

```
toBinary(){
    local n bit
    for (( n=$1 ; n>0 ; n >>= 1 )); do  bit="$(( n&1 ))$bit"; done
    printf "%s\n" "$bit"
}

$ toBinary 304       => 100110000
```

I'm not interested in a Perl or Python solution. The web is littered with them. I'm also familiar with all of the normal **bc** and **awk** hacks.

I'm more interested in understanding the algorithm in getting from ASCII text to base32 or base64, than getting a fast and easy solution with trickery.

This is the best I have so far - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/base-what-a-practical-introduction-to-base-encoding--net-27590

Comment: Why is Python or Perl "trickery"?  Base arithmetic in the shell is hardly a natural fit; why do you think a Bash solution would be a good way to understand the algorithm?

Comment: tripleee - it s a 'ship in the bottle' thing, it's the challenge of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code challenges are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Maybe see if you could make this fit on [codegolf.se].